# How to enable push notifications in iOS 8 for users who have previously accepted notifications?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I recently updated my app to conform to the new iOS 8 push notification changes. New users coming into the app are asked if they want to receive push notifications with the new popup and  everything works fine. However, old users who upgrade seem to be stuck in the old notification system - they never see the new popup and I am not able to get a fresh device token, and therefore they are not receiving push notifications. From what I understand it is impossible to re-prompt for this permissions dialogue whether the user has previously accepted or rejected. I'm assuming others have this issue, and if so what's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can open your app settings in iOS 8 via

```
if let appSettings = NSURL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(appSettings)
}
```

Hope that helps.